# Ruby throwing invalid encoding even with a forced encode

Tags: ruby, regex, utf-8

Uploading with Paperclip, Convert Encoding UTF-16LE to UTF-8, parsing with Regex and creating a new entry.

I'm working with some code that runs before save to parse information out of saved windows/osx system profile. The windows system profile is encoded in UTF-16LE (that's what text wrangler says) and is throwing out invalid byte errors when I use gsub or regex. I'm using ruby 2.2.1

```
file = '/Users/User/Desktop/HTPC-system.txt'



File.open(file) do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    puts line.gsub(/\bSystem\b/)
  end
end
```

Which returns and

```
#<Enumerator:0x007fdb19828240>
#<Enumerator:0x007fdb19828ad8>
#<Enumerator:0x007fdb1982a0b8>
#<Enumerator:0x007fdb1982aba8>
#<Enumerator:0x007fdb1a0eff40>
#<Enumerator:0x007fdb1a0efe00>
```

I've also tried this

```
open_file = '/Users/User/Desktop/HTPC-system.txt'
encoded_file = open_file.encode('UTF-16LE').encode('utf-8')



File.open('/Users/ncrmro/Downloads/HTPC-ncrmro.txt') do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    puts line.gsub(/\bSystem\b/, "")
  end
end
```

Which throws this error.

```
/Users/User/Desktop/TextParse.rb:10:in `gsub': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
from /Users/User/Downloads/TextParse.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
from /Users/User/Downloads/TextParse.rb:9:in `each_line'
from /Users/User/Downloads/TextParse.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/User/Downloads/TextParse.rb:8:in `open'
from /Users/User/Downloads/TextParse.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

Comment: please add the text of the error to your question.

Comment: Apologies added the code.

Comment: You are not re-encoding a file, but a file name in the beginning. Next, you can either load the whole file contents to convert to real UTF8, or do it with every line by using `if ! file_content.valid_encoding?
  s = file_content.encode("UTF-16be", :invalid=>:replace, :replace=>"?").encode('UTF-8')
  s.gsub(/dr/i,'med')
end
`